# Accessing Docker's volume using WinSCP

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, audio, docker, winscp

I have 2 Ubuntu 20.04.1 machines with Docker installed.
I would like to access the content of Docker volumes using WinSCP.
i.e. access the path `/var/lib/docker/volumes/my_vol_name/_data`

which is fully accessible using CLI and use of sudo.
But using WinSCP I now receive "Permission denied" error message.
**It was used to be possible using WinSCP and default settings up until some Linux updates ago.**

Additional details:

user being used to login using CLI and WinSCP:

```
$ id user1
uid=1000(user1) gid=1000(user1) groups=1000(user1),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),116(lxd)
```

The connection is done using SSH with password.

I know it is a Linux update reason as one of the machines I mentioned above was not used for a while and then when connected, it gave access on the WinSCP. The other machine was updated regularly and lately I noticed it denies access with the error above. I don't know which update caused the problem.
Unfortunately I had to update also the first machine and now it denies access as well.

I'm fully aware it might not be a problem but rather a 'security feature', but I'm looking for a solution not involving removing passwords or alike.
I've tried the solution mentioned here: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su but it didn't work for me. Not sure why.
Please let me know if additional details are needed.